# Kernel of $f$ is a maximal ideal in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R = \{a + b \sqrt{-3} \mid a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and define $f: R \to \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$ as $f(a+b\sqrt{-3}) = a - 2b + 7 \mathbb{Z}$.

Show that $f$ is surjective and that the kernel of $f$ is a maximal ideal in $R$.

I've already shown that the first part (surjectivity of $f$), but how do I use that to conclude that $\ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal?

Comment: First prove that $f$ is a ring homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $\;R\;$ is a unitary commutative ring, an ideal $\;M\le R\;$ is maximal iff $\;R/M\;$ is **a field** .